# How to populate a listbox with a dynamic range of cells in VBA/Excel

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, listbox

I've gone through several similar questions in hopes to solve my answer, but I've been struggling to connect the specific questions with my scenario.

I have a worksheet that has a button that opens a userform - this code runs in a standard module. Once the userform is open, I'd like to populate a listbox with a data from a range of cells that may vary with each spreadsheet.

[Here is the userform:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9ZJ9.png)

I know I have successfully grabbed my dynamic range of cells because I've been able to select the range with my code. Here is my code for the dynamic range:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim xrange, newStartCell As Range
Dim last_col As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Me.StartUpPosition = 0
Me.Top = 300
Me.Left = 475

' find cell with row header "cygnet code"
Set xrange = Cells.Find(What:="cygnet code", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Set newStartCell = xrange.Offset(, 1)

'This line gets the last column
last_col = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C&E")
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(newStartCell.Row, newStartCell.Column), .Cells(newStartCell.Row, last_col))
End With

With Me.ListBox1
    .List = rng.Value
End With

End Sub
```

I don't know if it has anything to do with running this code in the initialize function or if the way I'm grabbing the range is not compatible with the listbox? In either case, the code runs without "error" but the listbox remains blank (it adds one blank row).

Here is the code I used to test the selection tool working:

```
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C&E")
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(newStartCell.Row, newStartCell.Column), .Cells(newStartCell.Row, last_col))
    .Range(.Cells(newStartCell.Row, newStartCell.Column), .Cells(newStartCell.Row, last_col)).Select
    End With
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't start out by declaring the sheet to find `xrange` and `last_col`.  I would narrow down the search range for `xrange` instead of looking at every cell, but you do need the sheet.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim xrange, newStartCell As Range
    Dim last_col As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    
    Me.StartUpPosition = 0
    Me.Top = 300
    Me.Left = 475
    
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("C&E")
    
    ' find cell with row header "cygnet code"
    Set xrange = Sht.Cells.Find(What:="cygnet code", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    Set newStartCell = xrange.Offset(, 1)
    
    'This line gets the last column
    last_col = Sht.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Set rng = Sht.Range(Sht.Cells(newStartCell.Row, newStartCell.Column), Sht.Cells(newStartCell.Row, last_col))
    
    With Me.ListBox1
        .List = rng.Value
    End With
```

End Sub